# MYSQL - Calculating MTD in view, per Record/Row

Tags: mysql, sum

I am trying to figure out how create a view, that calculates Month to Date totals of the 'cattotal_food' field for each record.

sample data:

```
report_date, cattotal_food
2017-01-01, 100
2017-01-02, 100
2017-01-03, 100
2017-01-04, 100
```

Here is what I have now:

I created a function, called FIRST_DAY:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FIRST_DAY(input_date DATE) 
RETURNS DATE DETERMINISTIC
RETURN ADDDATE(LAST_DAY(SUBDATE(input_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)),1);
```

I then created a column in my view, to confirm it was selecting the correct date:

```
(select FIRST_DAY(report_date)) AS first_day_month,
```

This does infact, show the first day of the month the report was run.

So, when I incorporate it into my view, I get the same value in every row (which is the the total for the entire month, not the total up to the date listed in report_date).

```
(select sum(cattotal_food) from table 
WHERE report_date BETWEEN first_day_month AND report_date) as cattotal_food_mtd
```

With the code above, I my view looks like this:

```
report_date, cattotal_food, cattotal_food_MTD
2017-01-01, 100, 400
2017-01-02, 100, 400
2017-01-03, 100, 400
2017-01-04, 100, 400
```

I want it to look like this:

```
report_date, cattotal_food, cattotal_food_MTD
2017-01-01, 100, 100
2017-01-02, 100, 200
2017-01-03, 100, 300
2017-01-04, 100, 400
```

Any thoughts on how I can achieve this?
Thanks for any and all responses!

### UPDATE:

I tried the following query, which did **not** work:

```
IF (report_date = date_sub(report_date, interval day(report_date) -1 DAY), 
cattotal_food,
    (select cattotal_food + 
        (select sum(cattotal_food) 
        from table 
        where report_date >= date_sub(report_date, interval day(report_date) -1 DAY)
            AND report_date <= yesterday)))
            AS cattotal_food_mtd
from t;
```

However, if I calculate 'Yesterdays' date in another column and reference it in the query, then it **does** work.

```
sub_date(report_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) yesterday,
IF (report_date = date_sub(report_date, interval day(report_date) -1 DAY), 
    cattotal_food,
        (select cattotal_food + 
            (select sum(cattotal_food) 
            from table 
            where report_date >= date_sub(report_date, interval day(report_date) -1 DAY)
                AND report_date <=yesterday)))
    AS cattotal_food_mtd
from t;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A view is a pain.  You can do this using a correlated subquery:

```
select report_date, cattotal_food,
       (select sum(t2.cattotal_food)
        from t t2
        where t2.report_date >= date_sub(t.report_date, interval day(t.report_date) - 1 day) and
              t2.report_date <= t.report_date
       ) as cattotal_food_MTD
from t;
```

You don't need a function to calculate the first date of the month.  The `date_sub()` operation does this pretty easily.

The key to using correlated subqueries is to qualify your column names.

This formulation of the query also works for a view.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff, thanks for the response! I assume t1 and t2 are Table1 and Table2? I'm doing this all from the same table. When I enter the formula, without the t1 and t2, it still does the same thing (where I get the entire total for the month on every line, instead of the MTD up to that day. Any other thoughts?

Comment: `t2` is a table alias that refers to the table in the subquery.  There is no `t1` in the query.

Comment: Right on, thanks for the quick explanation. I changed the "t" in the code you provided to the name of my table and left the "t2" as is. Once I did that, the formula worked as expected. Thanks again for all your help!!